# How to add together and consolidate rows which share a username in a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreach

My project is a game where users try to predict scores of football matches and are awarded points based off of different criteria. I'm using MVC and Entity Framework.

I am trying to create a leaderboard that displays the total score for each user. I've got it to a certain point but I'm stuck on where to go next.

Currently I have the leaderboard displaying each prediction to the user using a foreach loop in the razor view.

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUser.UserName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PredCorrectScore)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PredCorrectResult)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Less15Goals)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Greater15Goals)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Less25Goals)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Greater25Goals)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Greater35Goals)</td>
        @{
            var totals = (item.PredCorrectScore + item.PredCorrectResult + item.Less15Goals + item.Greater15Goals + item.Less25Goals + item.Greater25Goals + item.Greater35Goals);
        }
        <td>@totals</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controller:

```
var predictions = db.Predictions
    .Include(p => p.AspNetUser)
    .Include(p => p.Prediction1)
    .Include(p => p.Match)
    .ToList();

return View(predictions);
```

This currently displays each entry users have made as individual rows (i.e The User 'Bob' has made 10 predictions so the table lists this as 10 rows)

I want the table to display the sum of each column for each username and then sort the table by highest total value.

For example, this is what it currently displays
[Currently in the View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVO9y.jpg)

In this table it should display 2 rows - one for Archer and one for Barry. Each numerical column should be the sum of all the values related to that username.

I've tried a few different ideas to tackle this problem but I'm yet to find a solution.

What can I use to have the view output in this way? Or is the solution a different approach all together?

Comment: you can either create a new model that has a Username property along with the score properties you want and create the new model in the controller using GroupBy() lambda expression..  or you can create an anonymous object in the foreach of your view..  Either way you will need to use GroupBy to group the records.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jamie. I will try what you suggest and report back if successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I meant by grouping the data in your foreach.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(g => g.AspNetUser.UserName).Select(s => new { UserName = s.Key, Data = s }).ToList())
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Sum(a => a.PredCorrectScore))</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Sum(a => a.PredCorrectResult))</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Sum(a => a.Less15Goals))</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Sum(a => a.Greater15Goals))</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Sum(a => a.Less25Goals))</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Sum(a => a.Greater25Goals))</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Sum(a => a.Greater35Goals))</td>
        @{
            var totals = (item.Data.Sum(a => a.PredCorrectScore)
                + item.Data.Sum(a => a.PredCorrectResult)
                + item.Data.Sum(a => a.Less15Goals)
                + item.Data.Sum(a => a.Greater15Goals)
                + item.Data.Sum(a => a.Less25Goals)
                + item.Data.Sum(a => a.Greater25Goals)
                + item.Data.Sum(a => a.Greater35Goals));
        }
        <td>@totals</td>
    </tr>
}
```

The `GroupBy` here will group the results by `UserName` (Key) and give you a `IEnumerable<Prediction>`  (Data).  Once you have this anonymous object you can use it in your DisplayFor helpers.  You can use `Sum()` to get the totals for each grouping

Answer (score 0):

Use a groupp by clause in your query
.GroupBy(g => g.AspNetUser.UserName)

```
var predictions = db.Predictions.GroupBy(g => g.AspNetUser.UserName)
.Select(g => new { username= g.AspNetUser.UserName, SumPredCorrectScore = g.Sum(i => i.PredCorrectScore) })
.Include(p => p.AspNetUser)
.Include(p => p.Prediction1)
.Include(p => p.Match)
.ToList();
```

Something like this, you will need to fill out the remaining fields and this is not tested but should get you going in the right direction.

J